# JQuery working wierdly for function 'find':

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following jQuery line:

```
$('<html><a href="cnn.com">hi</a></html>').find('a')
```

I expect the result to be a wrapped set of one element. However the result is an empty array (`[]`). Why?

**-- EDIT --**

For some reason the code below works.

```
$('<html><div><a href="cnn.com">hi</a></div></html>').find('a');
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: You will have a collection that contains just an `a` element. The `html` will be striped. As `a` doesn't and can't have an `a` descendant the `find` call won't return any element.

Comment: I do get `outerHTML: "<a href="cnn.com">hi</a>"` when doing `console.log($('<html><a href="cnn.com">hi</a></html>').find('a'));`.

Comment: @Vohuman That's just it. I get an empty array.

Comment: @Elad Katz `.find()` returns **descendants** of an element, not element itself

Comment: @hindmost yeah but 'a' is a descendant of 'html', no?

Comment: It is not about how `find()` works but about how `$(string)` works. `$('<html><span><a href="cnn.com">hi</a></span></html>').find('a')` this works as you expected. Try to see result of `$('<html><a href="cnn.com">hi</a></html>')` in console: it returns `<a></a>` element with `<html>` stripped out

Comment: why does it stripes the HTML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because the `html` element is stripped when the string is parsed:

```
> $('<html><a href="cnn.com">hi</a></html>')
[<a href=​"cnn.com">​hi​</a>​]
```

i.e. the current collection contains an element that you are trying to `find()`. As the top-level `a` element doesn't (and *can't*) have `a` descendants the `find()` call will return an empty collection.

From [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2):

> When passing in complex HTML, some browsers may not generate a DOM that exactly replicates the HTML source provided. As mentioned, jQuery uses the browser's `.innerHTML` property to parse the passed HTML and insert it into the current document. During this process, some browsers filter out certain elements such as `<html>`, `<title>`, or `<head>` elements. As a result, the elements inserted may not be representative of the original string passed.

**edit**: The second snippet can `find()`  `a` element as when the `html` element is stripped the top-level element of the collection is a `div` element that does have `a` descendant.

Comment: why is the 'html' tag being stripped?

Comment: @EladKatz according to the docs it's because of the combination of the creation of the jQuery-Object and it's use of the `innerHTML`-function

Comment: @empiric That's correct. Please note that `.innerHTML` is a property and not a function!

Answer (score 1):

As in the Documentation of [.find()](https://api.jquery.com/find/) descriped

> Get the descendants of each element in the current set of matched elements, filtered by a selector, jQuery object, or element.

```
$('<html><a href="cnn.com">hi</a></html>')
```

will just provide an Object of your `a`-tag.

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/v3322gax/)

If there are multiple anchor-tags inside your html-string you can filter them, e.g.:

```
var elem = $('<html><a href="cnn.com">hi</a><a href="cnn1.com">hi</a></html>');
var filter = elem.filter(function(){
    return $(this).attr('href') === "cnn.com";
});
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/qmbteqfu/)

**Edit**

> When passing in complex HTML, some browsers may not generate a DOM
>   that exactly replicates the HTML source provided. As mentioned, jQuery
>   uses the browser's .innerHTML property to parse the passed HTML and
>   insert it into the current document. During this process, some
>   browsers filter out certain elements such as `<html>`, `<title>`, or
>   `<head>` elements. As a result, the elements inserted may not be
>   representative of the original string passed.

Source: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2 down to the Paragraph `Creating New Elements`

So jQuery uses `.innerHTML`. According to the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML)

> Removes all of element's children, parses the content string and
>   assigns the resulting nodes as children of the element.

So the html-string `<html><a href="#">test</a></html>` gets stripped to `<a></a>`.
When wrapping a `div` around the anchor, the anchor stays a descendat of an elemnt and therefore gets found by the `.find()`-function.

Answer (score -1):

You should read the documentation at [Jquery docs about find()](https://api.jquery.com/find/)

```
$('html').find('a');
```

Check this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pzhpu8LL/)